Switching Amber Versions Mid-Project
Background: I have been running a large number of MD simulations in in the 2022 build of Amber for the last two years, as it is what I had available on my local supercomputer center. Recently, that center added a large number of new compute nodes with more, and faster GPUs.
Problem: I want to utilize these new nodes as they would drastically increase my throughput, but only AMBER24 is available at this time.
Question: Can I switch Amber MD versions (AMBER22 -> AMBER24) mid-project without undermining the integrity of my research?
Other than the application version change, everything else will remain the same (e.g., ff parameters, running on pmemd.cuda, etc.). My goal is to publish this work eventually, and I don't want to do anything that will come back to haunt me!
In the background I am trying to get a version of AMBER22 installed, but its a slow process as the technical support is busy with higher priority issues associated with setting up the new cluster, and I only have user level permissions.
I'm not familiar enough with the inner workings of these systems to make the judgement myself.

Here are your three options:
Switch immediately and completely to Amber24.
This is not as irresponsible as it might sound. With good data management, your simulation logs will tell you when you switched, so that you can identify any issues in retrospect.
When publishing your data, you can simply state "Simulations were performed in Amber22 or Amber24 (due to the latter version being released mid-project)." If you are scrupulous, you can include a list of which simulations were run in which version in your supplementary information. Most reviewers won't notice. I would notice, but I wouldn't put much weight on it; most papers are either wrong enough that the software version doesn't matter, or convincing enough that the software version doesn't matter.
Which raises a philosophical motivation for just switching. Suppose you found that the Amber24 results were wrong. Well, what makes you think the Amber22 results were correct? Maybe both versions were wrong. Maybe Amber22 had a bug that was corrected in Amber24. The point is -- if your results were that sensitive to the particular version of MD software used, then they're inherently not that robust, and you're going to be stuck doing lots of work to re-justify your science either way, so you might as well switch to the latest, fastest version and take the hits.
Stick with Amber22.
The no-operation operation. Keep this in your back pocket.
The real work of molecular dynamics is analyzing and interpreting results and communicating them to the wider community. It may well be that the extra work and effort of switching simply isn't worth the GPU speedup of churning out the trajectories.
Perform a managed transition.
Alright, you wanna do this rigorously? Here's how:

Benchmark the change for both precision and speed. Run a simulation you're confident about in both versions, then:
a. analyse the trajectories and extract your observables of interest. Are they statistically similar?
b. analyse the run times, including the increased allocation cost you're likely paying for GPU access. Is Amber24 really worth it?

Work out how much calculation you have left to do, and the expected speedup migrating to Amber24. Then subtract a full work-week or two learning all the little differences in input and output. Quantify the expected advantage in migrating.

Record the above results in your lab records so that future you will know exactly when and why you switched.


One last little tip:
If you see significant changes, and there isn't some obvious change in the actual algorithms used for calculation, then an easily-overlooked but consequential culprit can be single, double, or mixed floating-point precision in the compiled executable. CPU executables often use double precision, while GPU executables sometimes use mixed precision1, and the difference can be significant (primarily for very sensitive calculations with significant long-range electrostatic structuring).

1  single-precision for individual particle-particle force calculations, double when adding up forces and integrating positions and velocities.

Amazing, thank you so much! This is incredibly helpful in making my immediate decision and is a useful framework for making any similar decisions in the future. With some basic benchmarking I haven't found any discrepancies, and the time savings are well worth the cost!

With the old input data and unprocessed raw results by AMBER22 in hand, identify what are the properties in the output which are mission critical for your work.  A discussion with a colleague more experienced with MD in general, and your topic in particular could be helpful (because you started recently in this field).  Independent from this, it can prevent an accidental oversight.
In analogy to NIST's Statistical Reference Datasets, are there routinely used benchmarks?  Are there reports in the literature how these replicate with the more recent version of AMBER24?  If not (yet), for instance because they are tailored to your work, I would consider a to run the replication at your site and then compare "old results" vs "new results".  If there are numeric differences, are they i) statistically significant and yield these ii) at larger scale to chemical/physical meaningful differences (e.g., now an other protein folding becomes favorable)?
Because computer memory became so affordable today, organize input data, a note about the version of the program(s) used, and the unprocessed results e.g., by Amber in a folder structure managed by some sort of version control. Git* is a popular one.  Keep this separate from folders with the tools and scripts which eventually extract and post-process the data from the logs of Amber, Gaussian, etc.  And keep these -- raw data and tools to process them -- separate from the "workbench folders" where you actually apply these scripts on the raw logs of Amber.  This is one strategy to monitor origin and use of the data; not only to ease writing reports, but equally facilitate share and exchange with a colleague.
* In case you are not familiar with this, pull a chair to work through the classes of e.g., software-carpentry, and a summary (like the one by learnxinyminutes.com).  And don't forget a well maintained (and tested!) backup on top of version control.
